# Having trouble importing functions in python from my directory

Tags: python

As the title states I'm having trouble importing functions into my main.py file. I'm saving my project (first personal project ever) into a folder named `BillApp`.
 Within that folder I have the following files.
`main.py` `commands.py` `billapp.txt`

I'm attempting to import `commands.py` into my `main.py` code so that I can use the functions within `main.py`.

```
# This is the main code which will access the commands from commands.py
import commands

print 'Hello, Welcome to your friendly text-based bill reminder.'
print '\nI will be tracking all of your bills so you will never miss a payment again.'
print '\nLet\'s get started, please type on of the following commands.'

def userSelection():
    userSelection = raw_input('New \nSaved \nRemove \nAlerts')
    userSel = userSelection.lower()
    if userSel == 'new':
        commands.getDesc()
    elif userSel == 'saved':
        commands.savedBills()
    elif userSel == 'remove':
        commands.removeBills()
    elif userSel == 'alerts':
        commands.setAlerts()
    else:
        print 'Please enter a valid command'
        userSelection()
```

Here is my `commands.py` file just in case you want to take a look.

```
 def userSelection():
    userSelection = raw_input('New \nSaved \nRemove \nAlerts')
    userSel = userSelection.lower()
    if userSel == 'new':
        getDesc()
    elif userSel == 'saved':
        savedBills()
    elif userSel == 'remove':
        removeBills()
    elif userSel == 'alerts':
        setAlerts()
    else:
        print 'Please enter a valid command'
        userSelection()

def getDesc():
    desc = raw_input('\nHow do you want to describe this bill?\n')

def getAmnt():
    try:
        billAmnt = raw_input('How much is this bill?')
        amnt = float(billAmnt.strip('$'))
        return amnt
    except ValueError:
        print 'Please enter an amount that is at least 0'
        getAmnt()

def getDate():
    try:
        strDate = raw_input('What date of the month is this bill due?\nExample: 3rd\n')
        date = strDate.strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz')
        numDate = int(date)
        print numDate
    except ValueError:
        print 'Please enter the day of the month, for example. 3rd or 17th.'

def getFreqy():
    strFreqy = raw_input('How often do you have to pay this bill? \nMonthly, Weekly, or Once\n')
    freqy = strFreqy.lower()
    if freqy == 'monthly':
        print 'monthly'
    elif freqy == 'weekly':
        print 'weekly'
    elif freqy == 'once':
        print 'once'
    else:
        print 'Please enter either monthly, weekly, or once.'
        getFreqy()

def savedBills():
    print 'Here is a list of all of your bills.'
    # retrieve bills from database

def removeBills():
    print 'You wish to remove a bill from your list, very well, let\'s get started.',
    print 'Here\'s a list of all of your bills.'
    # retrieve a numbered list of all bills
    billNum = raw_input('What number bill would you like to remove?')
    if int.billNum:
        print 'We will remove that bill from your list.'
        waiting()
    else:
        print 'Please type in a corresponding number.'

def setAlerts():
    # pulls the current bill alert from database
    print 'Your bill alerts are currently set to %s.' % currentAlert
    change = raw_input("Would you like to change this?")
        if change == yes:
            # change bill alert in database
        else change == no:
            print 'Your bill alerts will continue as scheduled'
        elif:
            print 'Please enter either yes or no.'
```

Running `main.py` from the shell I get the following back.

```
MacBook-Pro:BillApp cmaher92$ sudo python main.py
Hello, Welcome to your friendly text-based bill reminder.

I will be tracking all of your bills so you will never miss a payment again.

Let's get started, please type on of the following commands.
New 
Saved 
Remove 
Alerts
>new
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    userSelection()
  File "main.py", line 11, in userSelection
    commands.getDesc()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getDesc'
Connor-Mahers-MacBook-Pro:BillApp cmaher92$
```

Comment: Do you get like a `Traceback` error message?...if so...do you mind post it please?

Comment: How are you running main.py?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Error message posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some basic debugging (you mixed up `else` and `elif` among some indentation and other errors like `change == yes`), this seems to work for me. Importing from `commands.py` is not the problem here.

At least I get to the part where it asks

> How do you want to describe this bill?

`main.py`

```
# This is the main code which will access the commands from commands.py
import commands

def userSelection():
    userSelection = raw_input('New \nSaved \nRemove \nAlerts')
    userSel = userSelection.lower()
    if userSel == 'new':
        commands.getDesc()
    elif userSel == 'saved':
        commands.savedBills()
    elif userSel == 'remove':
        commands.removeBills()
    elif userSel == 'alerts':
        commands.setAlerts()
    else:
        print 'Please enter a valid command'
        userSelection()

print 'Hello, Welcome to your friendly text-based bill reminder.'
print '\nI will be tracking all of your bills so you will never miss a payment again.'
print '\nLet\'s get started, please type on of the following commands.'
userSelection()
```

`commands.py`

```
def userSelection():
    userSelection = raw_input('New \nSaved \nRemove \nAlerts')
    userSel = userSelection.lower()
    if userSel == 'new':
        getDesc()
    elif userSel == 'saved':
        savedBills()
    elif userSel == 'remove':
        removeBills()
    elif userSel == 'alerts':
        setAlerts()
    else:
        print 'Please enter a valid command'
        userSelection()

def getDesc():
    desc = raw_input('\nHow do you want to describe this bill?\n')

def getAmnt():
    try:
        billAmnt = raw_input('How much is this bill?')
        amnt = float(billAmnt.strip('$'))
        return amnt
    except ValueError:
        print 'Please enter an amount that is at least 0'
        getAmnt()

def getDate():
    try:
        strDate = raw_input('What date of the month is this bill due?\nExample: 3rd\n')
        date = strDate.strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz')
        numDate = int(date)
        print numDate
    except ValueError:
        print 'Please enter the day of the month, for example. 3rd or 17th.'

def getFreqy():
    strFreqy = raw_input('How often do you have to pay this bill? \nMonthly, Weekly, or Once\n')
    freqy = strFreqy.lower()
    if freqy == 'monthly':
        print 'monthly'
    elif freqy == 'weekly':
        print 'weekly'
    elif freqy == 'once':
        print 'once'
    else:
        print 'Please enter either monthly, weekly, or once.'
        getFreqy()

def savedBills():
    print 'Here is a list of all of your bills.'
    # retrieve bills from database

def removeBills():
    print 'You wish to remove a bill from your list, very well, let\'s get started.',
    print 'Here\'s a list of all of your bills.'
    # retrieve a numbered list of all bills
    billNum = raw_input('What number bill would you like to remove?')
    if int.billNum:
        print 'We will remove that bill from your list.'
        waiting()
    else:
        print 'Please type in a corresponding number.'

def setAlerts():
    # pulls the current bill alert from database
    print 'Your bill alerts are currently set to %s.' % currentAlert
    change = raw_input("Would you like to change this?")
    if change == 'yes':
        # change bill alert in database
        pass
    elif change == 'no':
        print 'Your bill alerts will continue as scheduled'
    else:
        print 'Please enter either yes or no.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are executing the script from a context where it has access to your commands.py file. If you are executing it from the commandline there shouldn't be a problem (outside perhaps strange permissions issues), however if you use an IDE be sure that PYTHONPATH includes your file's location.